# Why isn't this Orchard (1.3.10) module noticing the changes I make to it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am following the tutorial here: http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1  But I'm having trouble with Part 4: http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-4 With one caveat, I'm writing code in VB.Net. With that said, I've completed Part 3 and been able create a new module (just by adding a simple Class Library) and having Orchard recognize and enable it. However, in Part 4 when I create the Migrations, ProductPart, and ProductRecord class, nothing happens. I do not get notifications that the module has been changed.

Admittedly, I have not done lambdas in VB.net before today and also this is my first time trying Auto Properties in VB.Net as well. But since there were no compile time errors, I assume I wrote the code correctly.

Here's my code for the 3 files:

```
Imports Orchard.ContentManagement.Records

Namespace Orchard.Webshop
    Public Class ProductRecord
        Inherits ContentPartRecord

        Public Overridable Property Price() As Decimal

        Public Overridable Property Sku() As String
    End Class
End Namespace


Imports Orchard.ContentManagement

Namespace Orchard.Webshop
    Public Class ProductPart
        Inherits ContentPart(Of ProductRecord)

        Public Property Price() As Decimal
            Get
                Return Record.Price
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                Record.Price = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Sku() As String
            Get
                Return Record.Sku
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Record.Sku = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace


Imports Orchard.Data.Migration
Imports Orchard.Core.Contents.Extensions
Imports Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData

Namespace Orchard.Webshop
    Public Class Migrations
        Inherits DataMigrationImpl

        Public Function Create()

            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ProductRecord", Function(table)
                                                           table.ContentPartRecord() _
                                                               .Column(Of Decimal)("Price") _
                                                               .Column(Of String)("Sku", Function(column)
                                                                                             column.WithLength(50)
                                                                                         End Function)
                                                       End Function)
            Return 1
        End Function

        Public Function UpdateFrom1()

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(GetType(ProductPart).Name, Function(part)
                                                                                        part.Attachable()
                                                                                    End Function)
            Return 2
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: In the admin dashboard u should see that u module can be 'updated' with an 'Update' link. Or is your problem that u don't see the 'update' link?

Comment: Correct. The problem is I don't see the Update link anywhere in the Admin Dashboard.

Comment: What do u see if u query the database table Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord for "Orchard.Webshop.Migrations"

Comment: Is your module enabled? Maybe u added your Migration class after enabling the module, which is wrong. U should have had a Migration class from the start with the Create method returning 1

Comment: My Create Method does return 1. It's in the code I posted. The author of the tutorial seems to be ok with Enable first. Then adding Migrations next. Is there a reason why that shouldn't work? Also, I posted deleted the VB code and replaced it with C# code. It seems to be working now.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: Shouldn't VB code work exactly the same as C#. Just based on this, it seems it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of Orchard, for a quick reference [codeplex source browser](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe93a818c376#src/Orchard/Data/Migration/DataMigrationManager.cs)

The Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationManager class uses reflection over all injected IDataMigration classes and it calls the following method

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the Create method from a data migration class if it's found
/// </summary>
private static MethodInfo GetCreateMethod(IDataMigration dataMigration) {
    var methodInfo = dataMigration.GetType().GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if(methodInfo != null && methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(int)) {
        return methodInfo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It seems that your VB Function doesn't has a ReturnType, so i believe it should work when u write your method as

```
Public Function Create() As Integer
    // do stuff
    Return 1;
End Function

Public Function UpdateFrom1() As Integer
    // do stuff
    Return 2;
End Function
```

Comment: I rewrote everything in C# and everything is working the way it should. However, you deserve the checkmark, given I made such a silly mistake and you have the code to show that silliness could have been the culprit. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't know VB much beside workflow expressions, so i learned from this myself :) Btw, it's wierd that VB just compiles a function without return type and returning a value. Yup a silly mistake, but who doesn't make mistakes?

Comment: Because I didn't specify a type it probably automatically returns Object.